# Project with path ':jtds-1.2.7' could not be found in project ':app'

Tags: android

I want to connect android app to SQL Server database. For this connection, i have tried to add up Jtds.jar file in Project library. After include this file when we click on sync now and Studio build the gradle and show this type of error.

Error:(25, 0) Project with path ':jtds-1.2.7' could not be found in project ':app'.

What's the actual problem? Anybody help me about fixation of this error

Comment: did you add your jar file in the libs folder of your source code?

Comment: yes...... I did

Answer (score 0):

In my case, work after extract .zip file

[image]

CLEAN PROJECT AFTER CHANGES: **build -> clean project**

Answer (score 0):

I think you get the Error Msg with Red color.

Don't worry this is the problem of .jar file path is not properly configure.

You fix this bug you must Follow the steps.

1). **File>Project Structure>** Click > **app** in a list

2). In center window on top have the tab Name Called **Dependencies** Click the Tab. In a list many lines will be listed as what is present in your Project have  **build.gradle(Module:app)** file.

3). Go to right corner of the window Click **+** button.

4). Find **jar Dependencies** or **File Dependencies** Click.

5). The new window will appear on the screen and choose the location of .jar file in your project and click **OK** button.

6). Finally the Project will be Sync automatically when you click **OK** button.